# Multiple frontend_enpoint in Azure Front Door with Terraform

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to build an Azure FrontDoor with Terraform but I am having an issue when I am trying to configure two Front Ends and then bind one of them to a custom HTTPS configuration. But I am getting the following error `The argument "frontend_endpoint_id" is required, but no definition was found.`

I just can't work out how you would specify two Front Door Endpoints and then reference one of them in a custom https config. Code below.

```html
resource "azurerm_frontdoor" "jccroutingrule" {
  depends_on = [
    cloudflare_record.create_frontdoor_CNAME,
    azurerm_key_vault.jctestingenv_keyvault,
    azurerm_key_vault_certificate.jcimportedcert
  ]
  name                = "testingfrontdoor"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.Terraform.name
  #enforce_backend_pools_certificate_name_check = false
  routing_rule {
    name               = "jccroutingrule"
    accepted_protocols = ["Http", "Https"]
    patterns_to_match  = ["/*"]
    frontend_endpoints = ["jccfrontendendpoint","frontendendpoint2"]
    forwarding_configuration {
      forwarding_protocol = "MatchRequest"
      backend_pool_name   = "jccbackendpool"
    }
  }

  backend_pool_load_balancing {
    name                        = "jccloadbalancesettings"
    sample_size                 = 255
    successful_samples_required = 1
  }

  backend_pool_health_probe {
    name                = "jcchealthprobesettings"
    path                = "/health/probe"
    protocol            = "Https"
    interval_in_seconds = 240
}


  backend_pool {
    name = "jccbackendpool"
    backend {
      host_header = format("portal-staging-westeurope.jason.website")
      address     = format("portal-staging-westeurope.jason.website")
      http_port   = 80
      https_port  = 443
      weight      = 50
      priority    = 1
      enabled     = true
    }

    load_balancing_name = "jccloadbalancesettings"
    health_probe_name   = "jcchealthprobesettings"
  }

  frontend_endpoint {
    name      = "jccfrontendendpoint"
    host_name = format("testingfrontdoor.azurefd.net")
  }

  frontend_endpoint {
    name      = "frontendendpoint2"
    host_name = format("portal-staging.jason.website")
  }

}

resource "azurerm_frontdoor_custom_https_configuration" "portal_staging_https_config" {
  frontend_endpoint_id              = azurerm_frontdoor.jccroutingrule.frontend_endpoint[1].id
  custom_https_provisioning_enabled = true

  custom_https_configuration {
    certificate_source                      = "AzureKeyVault"
    azure_key_vault_certificate_secret_name = "imported-cert"
    azure_key_vault_certificate_vault_id    = azurerm_key_vault_certificate.jcimportedcert.id
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this in the end, following this post on github: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/11456

What I had to in the end was change a couple of things, first I had to change the `frontend_endpoint_id` to  `"${azurerm_frontdoor.jccroutingrule.id}/frontendEndpoints/${local.frontendendpoint2}"` for some reason you need to make the `frontend_endpoint` name value into a local variable. So your code will look like this:

```html
frontend_endpoint {
    name      = local.frontendendpoint2
    host_name = format("portal-staging.jason.website")
  }
```

```html
resource "azurerm_frontdoor_custom_https_configuration" "portal_staging_https_config" {
  frontend_endpoint_id              = "${azurerm_frontdoor.jccroutingrule.id}/frontendEndpoints/${local.frontendendpoint2}"
  custom_https_provisioning_enabled = true

  custom_https_configuration {
    certificate_source                      = "AzureKeyVault"
    azure_key_vault_certificate_secret_name = "imported-cert"
    azure_key_vault_certificate_vault_id    = azurerm_key_vault_certificate.jcimportedcert.id
  }
}
```

Now if you build Frontdoor before doing the https_configuration you literally have to destroy your state file, for front door to build and then apply the custom HTTPS config. I could not get this to build without destroying the state file and someone else on the link I shared said the same.

Also the docs are wrong for `frontend_endpoint_id` if you choose not to use the format I have given and want to do something like:`azurerm_frontdoor.jccroutingrule.frontend_endpoint["frontendendpoint2"]` you must make sure you append .id on the end otherwise it won't look up the key values correctly and you will just get an error. Example: `azurerm_frontdoor.jccroutingrule.frontend_endpoint["frontendendpoint2"].id`

Also last point to note, you need to change frontend_endpoints under routing rule to include your local value like this: `frontend_endpoints = ["jccfrontendendpoint","${local.frontendendpoint2}"]` otherwise when you come to https custom config again the lookup will fail.

To be honest this frontdoor config is buggy at best and the docs on it are very vauge and in some places just wrong.

My full config to make it easy to follow:

```html
resource "azurerm_frontdoor" "jccroutingrule" {
  depends_on = [
    cloudflare_record.create_frontdoor_CNAME,
    azurerm_key_vault.jctestingenv_keyvault,
    azurerm_key_vault_certificate.jcimportedcert
  ]
  name                = "testingfrontdoor"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.Terraform.name
  #enforce_backend_pools_certificate_name_check = false
  routing_rule {
    name               = "jccroutingrule"
    accepted_protocols = ["Http", "Https"]
    patterns_to_match  = ["/*"]
    frontend_endpoints = ["jccfrontendendpoint","${local.frontendendpoint2}"]
    forwarding_configuration {
      forwarding_protocol = "MatchRequest"
      backend_pool_name   = "jccbackendpool"
    }
  }

  backend_pool_load_balancing {
    name                        = "jccloadbalancesettings"
    sample_size                 = 255
    successful_samples_required = 1
  }

  backend_pool_health_probe {
    name                = "jcchealthprobesettings"
    path                = "/health/probe"
    protocol            = "Https"
    interval_in_seconds = 240
}


  backend_pool {
    name = "jccbackendpool"
    backend {
      host_header = format("portal-staging-westeurope.jason.website")
      address     = format("portal-staging-westeurope.jason.website")
      http_port   = 80
      https_port  = 443
      weight      = 50
      priority    = 1
      enabled     = true
    }

    load_balancing_name = "jccloadbalancesettings"
    health_probe_name   = "jcchealthprobesettings"
  }

  frontend_endpoint {
    name      = "jccfrontendendpoint"
    host_name = format("testingfrontdoor.azurefd.net")
  }

  frontend_endpoint {
    name      = local.frontendendpoint2
    host_name = format("portal-staging.jason.website")
  }

}

resource "azurerm_frontdoor_custom_https_configuration" "portal_staging_https_config" {
  frontend_endpoint_id              = "${azurerm_frontdoor.jccroutingrule.id}/frontendEndpoints/${local.frontendendpoint2}"
  custom_https_provisioning_enabled = true

  custom_https_configuration {
    certificate_source                      = "AzureKeyVault"
    azure_key_vault_certificate_secret_name = "imported-cert"
    azure_key_vault_certificate_vault_id    = azurerm_key_vault.jctestingenv_keyvault.id
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

So from documentation of [azurerm_frontdoor](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/frontdoor) here, I see they export below field which I think is of your interest..

> frontend_endpoints - A map/dictionary of Frontend Endpoint Names (key)
> to the Frontend Endpoint ID (value)

`frontend_endpoints` is a map object containing endpoint name as key & the id as the value. So, you could make use of [lookup](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/lookup) function to extract value from the key.

In the end your `azurerm_frontdoor_custom_https_configuration` looks like below::

```
resource "azurerm_frontdoor_custom_https_configuration" "portal_staging_https_config" {
  frontend_endpoint_id              = lookup(azurerm_frontdoor.jccroutingrule.frontend_endpoints, "frontendendpoint2", "what?")
  custom_https_provisioning_enabled = true

  custom_https_configuration {
    certificate_source                      = "AzureKeyVault"
    azure_key_vault_certificate_secret_name = "imported-cert"
    azure_key_vault_certificate_vault_id    = azurerm_key_vault_certificate.jcimportedcert.id
  }
}
```

In case, if you change your mind to use `jccfrontendendpoint` endpoint, feel free to put that key into `lookup` function :-)

Answer (score -1):

from [terraform docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/frontdoor_custom_https_configuration):

```
resource "azurerm_frontdoor_custom_https_configuration" "portal_staging_https_config" {
  frontend_endpoint_id              = azurerm_frontdoor.jccroutingrule.frontend_endpoint["frontendendpoint2"]
  custom_https_provisioning_enabled = true

  custom_https_configuration {
    certificate_source                      = "AzureKeyVault"
    azure_key_vault_certificate_secret_name = "imported-cert"
    azure_key_vault_certificate_vault_id    = azurerm_key_vault_certificate.jcimportedcert.id
  }
}
```

Comment: The doc is wrong and is missing a key point, .id on the end of `azurerm_frontdoor.jccroutingrule.frontend_endpoint["frontendendpoint2"]` I have fixed this now will comment on what I had to do.

Comment: When I wrote this question, I didn't know the document was wrong. It was only investigating and spending a lot of time working through the issue. I then realised that the documentation was wrong. This question was never to show off my Knowledge.